# How to apply DRY with a tr

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I write the following statement with Razor?

```
   @{ 
    if (isOddRow)
    {
      <tr class="PadColumns">
    }
    else
    {
      <tr class="PadColumns AlternateRow">
    } 
    //then...
    <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    }
```

Razor gets mad and Intellisense busts.

so I tried wrapping my `tr's` in `<text>`

```
if (isOddRow)
{
  <text><tr class="PadColumns"></text>
}
```

...which causes a runtime parser error regarding `tr` with no matching start tag.

I would like to apply DRY by avoiding

```
   if (isOddRow)
    {
      <tr class="PadColumns">
          //then...
    <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    }
    else
    {
      <tr class="PadColumns AlternateRow">
    //then...
    <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just do something like this? Put the if statement inside the class attribute. If it's false, it'll print out AlternateRow, otherwise it prints out nothing.

```
<tr class="PadColumns @(isOddRow ? "" : "AlternateRow")">
```

Comment: Because I didn't think of that :D.  Actually, I didn't know that you could drop C# into code in such a way. +1